# img tag src issue in markdown using gatsby

Tags: markdown, gatsby

I have an image in the "static/img/" folder in gatsby.

I create a `blog_post.md` file similar to this:

```
<img src="/img/DSC_0050.jpg" alt="Tux, the Linux mascot">

![Tux, the Linux mascot](/img/DSC_0575.jpg)
```

When it is converted to html by gatsby only the markdown image has the correct path.

```
<img src="../../../static/img/DSC_0050.jpg" alt="Tux, the Linux mascot"> <- from img tag

<img src="/img/DSC_0575.jpg" alt="Tux, the Linux mascot"> <-from markdown
```

What do need to enter for it for gatsby to get the right path? I have tried setting it to
`./img/DSC_0575.jpg`, `../img/DSC_0575.jpg` and `img/DSC_0050.jpg` but I see no change in the output path.

---

Background info

1. I'm trying to layout an image that uses 33% of the container's width so I can have some text next to it.
2. I'm want to be able to do this for blog post, so using markdown would be nice.

Comment: u are missing the beginning slash

Comment: @Sysix I tried that too...no help.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the [gatsby-remark-images-anywhere](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-images-anywhere/) plugin to be able to use the img tag.

Additionally I cannot use the img inside a div tag. This still did not work:

```
<img src="/img/DSC_0050.jpg" alt="Tux, the Linux mascot">
```

I had to use the picture tag:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="/img/DSC_0050.jpg">
  <img src="/img/DSC_0050.jpg" alt="Tux, the Linux mascot">
</picture>
```

So using both the new plugin and the picture tag is required.